# Dehumidifier switch gives line voltage without load but <1V with load

Tags: electrical, wiring, appliances, troubleshooting, dehumidifier

I'm trying to troubleshoot and understand an issue with my dehumidifier. Its fan still runs but the compressor wouldn't turn on. I measure <1V between "Compressor" and "Neutral" but ~120V between "Fan High" and "Neutral". Strangely, if I disconnect the Faston spade connector at "Compressor", its voltage becomes ~120V; and if I connect the compressor wire to "Fan High", the compressor will run. This would suggest that the issue is at the "Compressor Switch" -- am I correct in this diagnosis? What kind of fault would cause it to behave this way?

[image: Dehumidifier PCB board]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~1V on the compressor power lead when wired as it's supposed to be, but the compressor runs when its power lead is touched to 120V, does sound like a bad compressor "switch", or the driver circuit that runs the "switch". It's actually a relay. The relay is either presenting a very high resistance when switched on, or it is not switching on, which is not correct.

I would suggest a new controller board for the dehumidifier.